# How to find books by title in Aldiko eBooks?

Tags: ebooks, aldiko

Can I do that? I found only the way to browse through the catalog and categories. How do I find a title in their collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the catalog has to support it.  I never realized that the default catalogs with Aldiko didn't have a sorting by title as I always use the custom catalog [Drinkmalk](http://www.drinkmalk.com/stanza/) and it does have a "By Title/Series" alphabetical ordering of books.

Comment: hi. I didn't find a way to install the catalog. I read [this](http://www.drinkmalk.com/stanza/node/1202), but didn't find "Download books" in first step, nor I found any option to add custom catalog.

Comment: hmm I found out that my Galaxy S' shipped aldiko is different than the market one.

Comment: @Louis the "download books" is on the first main screen of the app.  You may need to grab the latest from the market